# How to tell part of my image was shifted?

Tags: image-processing, convolution

I have a bunch of images that roughly speaking look like a bunch of stripes orientated in a random direction (so the stripes could be horizontal, vertical, at 45 degrees etc). I've noticed quite a few have a shift in them i.e. the stripes are misaligned along some line perpendicular to the stripes.

I'd like to get rid of these but I have too many images to go through by hand. Here's what I've tried so far.
If I threshold the image by curvature, I get a pretty good binary mask of the stripes (so it's just a black and white image of the stripes). I then tried to do a convolution with a kernel that I thought might emphasise the shift, but it didn't work. My kernel was also specific to pictures that were orientated at 0 degrees, so even if that had worked I would've had to then figure out how to apply the same idea to different orientations.

EDIT: adding in an example

original picture. The shift is a bit subtle so I've drawn a black line on it to make it more obvious where it is.
[image: original picture. The shift is a bit subtle so I've drawn a black line on it to make it more obvious where it is.]

The image after curvature thresholding.
[image: The image after curvature thresholding.]

Comment: Show samples please.

Comment: Given that the discontinuity is not a part of the scene photographed but an image digitization artifact, it is hard to believe that it could have arbitrary orientation. Can you show such a case ?

Comment: I'm actually finding it hard to find an example at the moment. There's a lot of data, and not many of the images have these faults. I understand why you think that it seems unlikely though.

Comment: @baker_man I happen to be working on a similar problem (using ML to detect image anomalies similar to this), I'm sure this is just a step to something more for you, but actually this is quite interesting in itself! please send me an email, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

A vertical Sobel followed by large horizontal Gaussian filtering reveals the breaks as faint but continuous lines. There is some hope to detect them by binarization, despite parasites.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I think that's actually worked quite well, as all I'd need to do next is look to see if the image has a line of ones. The issue would be if the white line isn't horizontal, but even if I'm able to get rid of some of these then that's already better.

Comment: @baker_man: warning: there is a little step on the left.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this and having some trouble. Did you use the original image or image that I had already done a curvature thresholding on? 
I'm trying a standard 3*3 vertical sobel, and I've tried a variety of gaussians (from 5*3 to 21*3) with sigma=3.